# Navigation Drawer and Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I all want is when I slide to other page on viewpager, specified navigaton drawer item should be checked. I know that I have to do it in viewpager listener, but how? I couldnt manage it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add addOnPageChangeListener to your ViewPager and in your onPageSelected(int position) you have to enable the checked state of your navigation menu item.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true); // where 0,1,2.. etc. are the indexes/positions for your menu items
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So based on the viewpager tab selected you want to make the navigation drawer item selected so you can do the following:

1.Get onTabSelected() listener

2.inside that method check which tab is selected

3.Based on the item selected you can use this method `navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);`

Comment below if you need any further info